# How to extend a zero component tuple in C#

Tags: c#, tuples, valuetuple

ValueTuples in C# are mutable. Is it possible to create a ValueTuple with no elements and then add elements to it at a later time?
Kind of like how we can instantiate a list and add the list items afterward.

Comment: "Mutable" here means that each element can be mutated. It does not mean that the arity of the tuple can be changed. A 2-element tuple must always have 2 elements - you can't add a 3rd, even though you can change the 2 elements. We don't say that a `string` can be mutated into an `int`, for example, and `ValueTuple<T1, T2>` and `ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3>` are distinct types, just as `string` and `int` are distinct types

Comment: You can create extensions method for tuple, that will create new tuple with increased arity

Comment: If you're really trying to add values to a tuple, then I would suggest you're possibly doing something bad and should consider refactoring, or not using tuples.

Comment: So you want a `List<object>`?

Comment: @canton7 Thanks a lot. That settles my confusion